# PHP+Kendo Grid ServerPaging first Page lists all entries

Tags: php, kendo-ui, grid, remote-server

I've got a working kendo grid with remote data from the webserver.

But the paging isn't working as expected. If the page gets loaded the first time, or I click on page 1 the server returns all the data available.

If I click on page 2 oder every other page than the first one it works fine.

The query seems to be correct as you can see in the screenshot from firebug.
[image]

So anyone got a hint for me where to look at?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the problem. I was removing empty parameters on the serverside. So I was throughing away the "skip" which screwed the query up.